# Java socket delay

Tags: java, sockets

I am going to read from a socket in java. Here is what I am going to do:

```
System.out.println("Start Reading");
/* bab is socket connector */
/* and readLine is the method below.
/* public String readLine()throws IOException
{
    String a = inStream.readLine();
    return a;
}
*/
for( int j=0;j<9;j++)
{
    response = bab.readLine();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

I see a lot of delay (2-3 seconds) between printing "start Reading" and first line of the response. But when I requested it with Firefox, it responsed quickly (20 ms). What is the problem? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `bab`? and what do you mean by "when I requested it with firefox"?

Comment: bob is a socket connector.and I enter exact below
bab.connect("192.168.2.193",8080);
in firefox.

Comment: The reason I was asking what `bab` is, was because I wanted to see if you were using a `BufferedReader` or not. Try this code in the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) and see if there is a time delay. Also, see if there is a time delay if you connect within the same program a second time. I suspect there will not be a delay.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is the server doesn't send the line-delimiter for some time, so the `readLine()` method waits. I bet if you just do `readByte()` it must be quick.

As Firefox or any other browser wouldn't read line by line, it dosn't affect them.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox is probably caching the response and is therefore able to display it very quickly to you. I suggest you clear the cache on Firefox and time it again.

If you are using a domain name for the call then Firefox will also cache the DNS lookup which could save time in Firefox whereas making the call in Java could require a DNS lookup.

If you are using Windows then download [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29)  which will allow you to monitor the HTTP connection and give you a better idea of what is happening.